# Meaning of "engineer" as a hotel employee

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, terminology

During a short stay at a hotel in Manhattan, I had a problem with the sink drain getting clogged. I rang the reception and described the problem. They replied: "I will send an engineer up right away".

What does "engineer" mean in this case? Surely they didn't send a highly specialised and probably expensive professional to do something as simple as operating a plunger. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [hotel maintenance engineer](https://climbtheladder.com/hotel-maintenance-engineer/) (according to careers website Climbtheladder.com):

> Hotel maintenance engineers are responsible for keeping hotels clean, safe, and in good working order. They commonly work with a team of other hotel employees to ensure that all aspects of the hotel stay clean, safe, and well-maintained at all times.

Responsibilities may include

> Reviewing work orders to determine whether they are complete and accurate
>
> Coordinating with architects, designers, contractors, and other construction professionals to ensure that new construction projects meet building codes
>
> Conducting inspections of facilities to identify potential problems in need of repair or maintenance
>
> Inspecting equipment to ensure proper functioning of heating, cooling, ventilation, plumbing, electrical systems, etc.
>
> Troubleshooting problems with equipment to determine the cause of failure and determine the best solution for repair or replacement
>
> Recommending changes to building plans to ensure compliance with applicable codes and regulations
>
> Performing maintenance activities such as replacing light bulbs and air filters, repairing leaky pipes or broken appliances, and painting walls
>
> Installing new fixtures, equipment, and appliances as needed
>
> Maintaining inventory of building materials and supplies using computerized inventory tracking systems

Typical qualifications are a high school diploma and possibly a hospitality qualification, so it's not a job that requires an engineering degree.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can call themselves an “*engineer*”.

In the UK at least it’s not a protected title as per [www.gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/incorporation-and-names/annex-c-other-regulated-words-and-expressions--2) page and I expect same in US.

Engineer institutes e.g. the IET in the UK, do have reserved terms like *Chartered Engineer* or *Incorporated Engineer*, quoting their [website](https://www.theiet.org/membership/manage-your-membership/using-designatory-letters/):

> You should use your Engineering Council letters after your decorations or degrees, and before your IET membership letters:
> •   A B Smith OBE MEng CEng FIET
> •   A B Smith OBE BSc IEng MIET
> •   A B Smith OBE EngTech TMIET
> Or you can use the title in full at the end, like this:
> •   A B Smith OBE MIET Incorporated Engineer

Comment: Thank you. I think this might be something specific to the UK, US and perhaps other countries in the English-speaking world. Very interesting!